# Change order of ViewPager and update views

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a ViewPager with 10+ views. I wish to change the order of the pages occasionally i.e.

Page 1 | Page 2 | page 3

to

Page 3 | Page 1 | Page 2

For the tabs I am using [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), I am able to update the order of these by changing the order of my adapter and calling:

```
mViewPagerIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However, what I cannot update is the content of the ViewPager, for example if I update the ViewPager adapter (to the new order I wish the pages to be in) and call:

```
mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
```

This has no effect. The tab indicator bar is updated fine but the content of the page still shows the old order.

Is there a way to change the order of pages in a ViewPager adapter and get the ViewPager to reload all it's views?

---

My ViewPager adapter extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and my overridden methods are as follows:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MyCustomFragment.newInstance();
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    //super.destroyItem(container, position, object);  // Commented out to ensure views are not destroyed
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to do with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` because you'll have to implement the logic yourself, but it's a lot easier with `FragmentPagerAdapter` which already provides the functionality for this purpose.

Calling `.notifyDataSetChanged()` invokes the `getItemPosition(Object object)`-method of your adapter. This is where you should provide ViewPager with the information of where to put the Fragment passed in the parameter `object`, by returning the page-number you want the Fragment to be positioned on.

For an example on how to do this, [check out my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321617/android-viewpager-move-any-page-to-end-programatically/14822077#14822077).

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't super important, it's really easy to force the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter` to redraw (invalidate) all of its views/fragments: just override `getItemPosition` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` as you normally would.

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE; //In source code, POSITION_NONE = -2 FYI
}
```

For more info, check out my post: [How to use orderByKey() in descending order instead of ascending #Askfirebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627149/how-to-use-orderbykey-in-descending-order-instead-of-ascending-askfirebase/38668756#38668756)